# Boto Socket timeout when provisioning EC2 instance using ansible

Tags: ansible, boto

I have a simple ansible playbook to create an AWS-EC2 instance.

I have the AWS access key and secret key in the environment variables. It seems to me, `boto` is timing out while trying to connect to AWS?

The following are the details on hosts, playbook, error log from terminal. Could this be a proxy related issue? I have the `https_proxy` set in my environment.

Have gone through other blogs and the questions on stackoverflow but couldn't solve this.

My ansible **host file** has following.

`[localhost]`
`127.0.0.1`

```
--- # Create ec2 instance playbook

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    inst_name: "What's the name of the instance?"
  vars:
      keypair: ".pem name here?? <<I already have ec2 instance that i created manually, using same key name here>>"
      instance_type: "t2.large"
      image: "ami-3d409b56"
      group: "securityGroup here"
      region: "us-east-1"
  tasks:
    - name: make one instance
      ec2: image={{ image }}
           instance_type={{ instance_type }}
           instance_tags='{"Name":"{{ inst_name }}"}'
           region={{ region }}
           group={{ group }}
           vpc_subnet_id="subnet-dfb490a8"
           wait=true
      register: ec2_info

    - name: Add instances to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=ec2hosts
      with_items: ec2_info.instances

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for: host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
      with_items: ec2_info.instances



****Error:****
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445631523.13-62493682297224/ec2", line 3070, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445631523.13-62493682297224/ec2", line 1249, in main
    (instance_dict_array, new_instance_ids, changed) = create_instances(module, ec2, vpc)
  File "/var/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445631523.13-62493682297224/ec2", line 792, in create_instances
    vpc_id = vpc.get_all_subnets(subnet_ids=[vpc_subnet_id])[0].vpc_id
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/vpc/__init__.py", line 1153, in get_all_subnets
    return self.get_list('DescribeSubnets', params, [('item', Subnet)])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1170, in get_list
    response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1116, in make_request
    return self._mexe(http_request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
socket.timeout: timed out
```

New Error after adding proxy:

```
failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n'
send: 'POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 48\r\nUser-Agent: Boto/2.38.0 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/14.5.0\r\nHost: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r\nX-Amz-Date: 20151025T132220Z\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nAuthorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=MyKEYHere/20151025/us-east-1/ec2/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date,Signature=someSignature\r\n\r\nAction=DescribeSecurityGroups&Version=2014-10-01'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n'
```

Comment: i added following line in my ansible task and now getting 401 exception. Looks like it is now able to talk to AWS atleast? Seems it is not taking access key from my env variables? 'environment:
          http_proxy: http://user:password@proxy:port'                              raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error>

Answer (score 0):

never mind.. got past both the errors. Boto Socket timeout - which was due to proxy as i mentioned earlier. And second one - AWS authorization which was due to missing parameter 'profile' in my ansible script.

```
 local_action: ec2 instance_tags="Name=AnsibleTest"
                  instance_type={{ instance_type}}
                  image={{ image }}
                  wait=true
                  group_id={{group_id}}
                  **profile=ProfileToWhichMyUserBelongsTo**
```